# combining these 2 case when statements

Tags: sql-server

The below case statement works, returning Yes where value = 1 for `col1`. How can I include the 2nd when for `col2`?

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN col1= '1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END 
FROM PROVIDERS
WHERE NAME = 'Hospital1'
```

The below gives erros

```
 SELECT CASE 
(WHEN col1= '1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 1st,
(WHEN col2= '1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 2nd
    FROM PROVIDERS
WHERE NAME = 'Hospital1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is missed in Second column

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN col1 = '1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 1st,
       CASE WHEN col2 = '1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 2nd
FROM   PROVIDERS
WHERE  NAME = 'Hospital1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Formatted correctly:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN col1 = '1'
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS 1st
    ,CASE 
        WHEN col2 = '1'
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS 2nd
FROM PROVIDERS
WHERE NAME = 'Hospital1'
```